# SilverStripe 3 - Hiding the BlogEntry pagetype in Add page form

Tags: silverstripe

I have extended the BlogEntry class and added three new pagetypes: -

```
class ResourceBlogEntry extends BlogEntry { ... }
class NewsBlogEntry extends BlogEntry { ... }
class MediaBlogEntry extends BlogEntry { ... }
```

They are showing up fine in the new page list when I try to add a child page of a BlogHolder. The problem is the original BlogEntry pagetype is still showing up in the list and I can't remove it. I have tried all the methods on the following page without success: -

http://www.balbus.tk/hide-a-page-from-the-cms-pagetype-dropdown/

I don't know what I am doing wrong.

FYI, this website is using SilverStripe version 3.1.

MORE INFO

I have also used a dataextension on the BlogEntry page type, I don't know if that is the problem.

```
class CustomBlogEntry extends DataExtension {
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do this by setting the `hide_ancestor` static to the name of the class you want to hide.

In this case, you'd use

```
class ResourceBlogEntry extends BlogEntry 
    private static $hide_ancestor = 'BlogEntry';
}
```

Remembering to flush after you add it.

Comment: Thanks Simon. I worked out I'd messed up when attempting to flush, your answer helped me double check and see what I was doing wrong :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the `hide_ancestor` flag on one of your subclasses. In SilverStripe 3.1+ you need to configure this using a private static:

```
class ResourceBlogEntry extends BlogEntry {
    private static $hide_ancestor = true;
}
```

Comment: @Zauberfisch I have it working now thanks. "isn't working" meant I was still getting an option for Blog Entry in the add page form.

Comment: *EDIT/REMOVED* missed the post by simon, making my comment useless.